# format date from json result and display in table angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

i do a get request to a page that returns a json with dates in format "dd/MM/yyyy".
i parse it and i display it in a table such as below

```
<script>
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("mainController", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('backList.php',{params: {dta: $scope.dataSelected}})
            .success(function(data) { if("null" == data) 
                                        $scope.list=""; 
                                    else {
                                        $scope.list=data;
                                    }
                                    } )
            .error(function() { alert("Error retrieve data!"); });
    }
});
</script>

<body ng-controller="mainController">
<div>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in list">
      <td align="center">{{row.dta_example}}</td>
      <td align="center"><input class="calendar" type="text" ng-model="row.dta_example" ng-value="row.dta_example" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

everything works fine but i'd like to use type="data" so that pops-out a calendar but if i use that i get an error that tells me that row.dta_example need to be a Date() object.

so i did something like this in the success method of the get call:

```
.success(function(data) { if("null" == data) 
                                        $scope.list=""; 
                                    else {
                                        $scope.list=data;
                                        var i = 0;
                                        for(var key in $scope.list){
                                            $scope.list[i].dta_example=new Date.exactmatch(key.dta_example)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    } )
```

but fails.

Comment: Just a comment about dates - I would never use anything other than momentjs again, it'll make your life so much easier - http://momentjs.com

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$scope.list[i].dta_example = new Date(key.dta_example);
```

Also, 'null' does not = null. That test wont work unless your code passes back a string of 'null' somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Use [momentjs.com](http://momentjs.com/) in filter.

```
<script>
  angular.module("myApp",[])
  .controller("mainController", function($scope, $http) {
     $http.get('backList.php',{params: {dta: $scope.dataSelected}})
        .success(function(data) { if("null" == data) 
                                    $scope.list=""; 
                                else {
                                    $scope.list=data;
                                }
                                })
        .error(function() { alert("Error retrieve data!"); });
      }
   });
  angular.module("myApp").filter('momentFilter', function () {
     return function (date) {
       if (date === null || !angular.isDefined(date))
         return null;
       if (moment(date).isValid()) {
         return moment(date).format('DD. MM. YYYY HH:mm');
       }
       return date;
    }
  });
</script>

<body ng-controller="mainController">
<div>
 <table>
   <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="row in list">
       <td align="center">{{row.dta_example | momentFilter }}</td>
       <td align="center"><input class="calendar" type="text" ng-model="row.dta_example" ng-value="row.dta_example" /></td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: i added to your code ng-value="row.dta_example | momentFilter" and modify the format to moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');  but stil is not correct. if i put a date like 12/12/2012 i get this warning "The specified value "12/12/1902" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"". and row.dta_example is populated such as "Wed Dec 12 2012......." and i want it to be as i posted so "12/12/2012"